# In XPath what is the difference between parent and ancestor?

Tags: html, xml, xpath, webdriver

I am seeing 2 different axis in XPath

1. parent
2. ancestor

Is `ancestor[1]` is equal to `parent`? i.e.,

```
//*[text()='target_text']//ancestor::div[1]
```

is equal to

```
//*[text()='target_text']//parent::div
```

Answer (score 18):

The difference between `parent::` and `ancestor::` axis is conveyed by their names:
A *parent* is the immediately direct *ancestor*.

So, for this XML for example,

```
<a>
  <b>
    <c>
      <d/>
    </c>
  </b>
</a>
```

- `/a/b/c/d/parent::*` selects `c`
- `/a/b/c/d/ancestor::*` selects `c`, `b`, and `a`

So, yes `/a/b/c/d/ancestor::*[1]` would be the same as `/a/b/c/d/parent::*`.

Comment: Nicely explained.

Comment: Nice explanation, thank you.